# Change DropDownListFor content based on other DropDownListFor content using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I could use some advice in order to create a new list based on the selected input in the first dropdownlist.

What I'm trying to do is when a user selects something in the DropDownList, it should reload somehow (not the whole page) and generate a new list which will be shown in the 2nd dropdownlist.

To explain this better, I have created two DropDownListFor --> Departure route and Return route. The data they have is shown under here:

**Departure dropdown:**

```
<p>
    @Html.Label("Departure route:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departureroute, Model.RoutesList, new { @class = "dropdownlist", @id = "departureroute" })
</p>
```

The ***Model.RoutesList*** comes from the following method:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Routes()
    {
        var routes = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = "OsCo", Text = "Oslo - Copenhagen"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "CoOs", Text = "Copenhagen - Oslo"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "CoSt", Text = "Copenhagen - Stockholm"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "StCo", Text = "Stockholm - Copenhagen"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "OsSt", Text = "Oslo - Stockholm"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "StOs", Text = "Stockholm - Oslo"},
        };
        return routes;
    }
```

**Return dropdown:**

I'm not sure if I should have this method because i want to create a new list and only show the routes which is valid.

```
<p>
    @Html.Label("Return route:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Returnroute, Model.RoutesListConversely, new { @class = "dropdownlist", @id = "returnroute" })
</p>
```

The Model.RoutesListConversely comes from this data:

```
public List<SelectListItem> RoutesConversely()
    {
        var routesconversely = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = "CoOs", Text = "Copenhagen - Oslo"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "OsCo", Text = "Oslo - Copenhagen"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "StCo", Text = "Stockholm - Copenhagen"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "CoSt", Text = "Copenhagen - Stockholm"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "StOs", Text = "Stockholm - Oslo"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "OsSt", Text = "Oslo - Stockholm"},
        };
        return routesconversely;
    }
```

As you see, I have set the values like **"CoOs"** which stands for Copenhagen to Oslo. When a user selects, lets say Stockholm - Copenhagen in the departure route dropdownlist, it has the value = "StCo".

I want to create a new list each time a user selects a new route in the departure route dropdownlist. If the departure route is Stockholm - Copenhagen "StCo" then the return route dropdownlist should contain the fields "Copenhagen - Stockholm "CoSt" and Copenhagen - Oslo "CoOs" and not all.

I'm not sure what the right way to do this is, but have read that Ajax is something I should look at.
Any suggestions on how I can do this?